# Rendering multiple boxes only displays correctly if perfectly squared

Tags: javascript, graphics, three.js

I'm using some logic to add boxes to my scene, based on how many items in height, width and depth, and that works well when they are all perfectly squared.

[image]

The problem comes if I want to use a different rectangular form:

[image]

I am quite a beginner at this. How can I correct it?

```
private addCubes() {
     // geometry
 const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1,4,4);
 const edgesGeometry = new THREE.EdgesGeometry(geometry);

 // material
 const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
   color: 0x0d6efd,
 });
 const edgesMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
   color: 0x000000
 });

  // positions
for (let x = 0; x < 2; x++) {
  for (let y = 0; y < 1; y++) {
    for (let z = 0; z < 2; z++) {
      // mesh
      const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
      mesh.scale.multiplyScalar(0.9);
      mesh.position.set(x, y, z);
      this.scene.add(mesh);

      const lines = new THREE.LineSegments(edgesGeometry, edgesMaterial);
      mesh.add(lines);
    }
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `mesh.position.set(x, y, z)` to `mesh.position.set(x, y, z * 4)`.  Your boxes are 4 units deep in the z direction, but you're only moving the second rank of boxes by 1 unit, so they're overlapping.

Comment: Thanks ! :) 

result ended up with this : 
 const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(this.itemWidth,this.itemHeight,this.itemDepth);
 mesh.position.set(x * this.itemWidth, y * this.itemHeight, z * this.itemDepth);

Only annoying issue i have to fix now is that when rendering out multiple items, the camera is _inside_ the object, so have to zoom out 50 times to get it visible :) hehe..